Clear all data in UserDefault when init OpenTelemetry
OpenTelemetry.registerTracerProvider(tracerProvider: TracerProviderBuilder()
         .add(spanProcessor: SimpleSpanProcessor(spanExporter: OtlpHttpTraceExporter(endpoint: endpoint, useSession: session)))
         .with(resource: resource)
         .build())

After I init openTelemetry, all data in UserDefault is removed. How to keep data when init it.
(Only get this error when ios >= 16)

How have you determined that all data in UserDefaults is removed? (If this is really the case, then it sounds like a bug in OpenTelemetry, and likely you would need to work with them to resolve it.)

@RobNapier I printed all value in UserDefault before and after init OpenTelemetry

You can store them and put them back if you like, but I'm not sure what answer would make sense other than "open a bug with OpenTelemetry" or "stop using a framework that deletes UserDefaults." What kind of answer are you hoping for here? I believe it's open source, so you can go look at the code.

I created an issue with Open Telemetry, but not receive any answer.

@Chung I saw your question: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-swift/issues/586
It seems to be an Apple issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/741719
